large white area under the table using xtabular
When doing a long table in two-column mode using xtabular, LaTeX leaves a great deal of white space before it flips the table to the next page/column. If there is no text above the table and it is in a new section then it just starts in a clean column. I have already tried using the \flushbottom and \raggedbottom commands and nothing helps. If I remove begin{center} from the code the whole thing works even worse and completely flips the table to a new column even if there is text above it. If i remove '\textcolor{white}{.}' (in the below example I only use '.' above table) from the code table will start next column, deleting the caption doesn't help either. I did a little more research and found that this may be due to LaTeX wanting to leave too much space for the signature. However, I can't find how to change this.
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xtab}

\begin{document}
    
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{7pt}
    {
    \topcaption{Some Caption} 
    \tablefirsthead{ \multicolumn{5}{c}{first line}
    \\\toprule 1& 2& 3& 4& 5\\ \midrule}
    \tablehead{
    \multicolumn{5}{c}
    {{  \thetable\}} \\
    \toprule
    1  & 2  & 3  & 4 & 5 \\ \midrule}
    \tabletail{
    \midrule}
    \tablelasttail{%
    \bottomrule}
     \begin{center}\begin{xtabular}{c|cccc}
     \multicolumn{5}{c}{some text}   \\\midrule
    1.   & text         & text          & text      & text              \\
    2.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    3.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    4.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    5.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    6.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    7.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    8.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    1.   & text         & text          & text      & text              \\
    2.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    3.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    4.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    5.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    6.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    7.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    8.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    1.   & text         & text          & text      & text              \\
    2.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    3.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    4.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    5.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    6.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    7.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    8.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    1.   & text         & text          & text      & text              \\
    2.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    3.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    4.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    5.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    6.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    7.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    8.   & text         & text          & text      & text               \\
    
    \end{xtabular}
    \end{center}
    }
\end{document}



Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

To support, you may want to run your posted code through this process: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137
